# Elasticsearch: High CPU usage by Lucene Merge Thread

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a ES 2.4.1 cluster with 3 master and 18 data nodes which collects log data with a new index being created every day. In a day index size grows to about 2TB. Indexes older than 7 days get deleted. Very few searches are being performed on the cluster, so the main goal is to increase indexing throughput.

I see a lot of the following exceptions which is another symptom of what I am going to say next:

```
EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4@5a7d8a24 on EsThreadPoolExecutor[bulk, queue capacity = 50, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@5f9ef44f[Running, pool size = 8, active threads = 8, queued tasks = 50, completed tasks = 68888704]]];]];
```

The nodes in the cluster are constantly pegging CPU. I increased index refresh interval to 30s but that had little effect. When I check hot threads I see multiple "Lucene Merge Thread" per node using 100% CPU. I also noticed that segment count is constantly around 1000 per shard, which seems like a lot. The following is an example of a segment stat:

```
"_2zo5": {
  "generation": 139541,
  "num_docs": 5206661,
  "deleted_docs": 123023,
  "size_in_bytes": 5423948035,
  "memory_in_bytes": 7393758,
  "committed": true,
  "search": true,
  "version": "5.5.2",
  "compound": false
}
```

Extremely high "generation" number worries me and I'd like to optimize segment creation and merge to reduce CPU load on the nodes.

Details about indexing and cluster configuration:

- Each node is an i2.2xl AWS instance with 8 CPU cores and 1.6T SSD drives
- Documents are indexed constantly by 6 client threads with bulk size 1000
- Each index has 30 shards with 1 replica
- It takes about 25 sec per batch of 1000 documents
- /_cat/thread_pool?h=bulk*&v shows that bulk.completed are equally spread out across nodes
- Index buffer size and transaction durability are left at default
- _all is disabled, but dynamic mappings are enabled
- The number of merge threads is left at default, which should be OK given that I am using SSDs

What's the best way to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: How often are you indexing documents?  ESRejectedExecutionExceptions that output the bulk queue related values typically mean you are overloading the cluster with bulk requests.

Comment: How many replicas do you have? How many shards are writeable at any point in time? What is your bulk size? Do you know how large your average bulk request is? How long does each bulk insert take in ms, on average? When you look at /_cat/threadpool?h=bulk*&v, are the bulk requests spread around the cluster or are they beating up a few select nodes? Have you increased your index buffer size? Have you looked at setting translog durability to async? Have you disabled _all? Are you permitting dynamic mappings?

Comment: Also are you using ssds or spindles? How many merge threads do you have?

Comment: If I had to guess, based on what you are describing, translog durability and index buffer size will probably give you the most bang for your buck. But all of the above questions are relevant and it could just as easily be too few shards or merge thread settings that are too high

Comment: Evanv, I added answers to your questions in the OP. I will try setting  index.translog.durability: async and indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 70%.

Comment: @evanv, it's not clear if indices.memory.index_buffer_size can be updated via REST API as any other "static" setting before index creation (per  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/index-modules.html) or has to be set in elasticsearch.yml on every node (per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/indexing-buffer.html).

Comment: It has to be placed in elasticsearch.yaml and you will need to a restart.

Comment: Okay based on the info you added, I'd increase your index_buffer_size to 1gb and set the translog durability to async. To be clear, are you saying that the each actual http request takes 25 seconds for only 1000 docs? how big are these docs?

Comment: inre `/_cat/thread_pool?h=bulk*&v shows that bulk.completed are equally spread out across nodes`, averages over time aren't gonna help you spot hotspots. but with 30 primary shards and 18 nodes, something i would suggest trying is reducing that to 18 shards or increasing it to 36. as it is now, it's very likely that 6 of your 18 nodes are gonna be doing half the amount of work as the other nodes that have 2 primary shards on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the optimizations I made to the cluster to increase indexing throughput:

- Increased threadpool.bulk.queue_size to 500 because index requests were frequently overloading the queues
- Increased disk watermarks, because default settings were too aggressive for the large SSDs that we were using. I set "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "100gb" and "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "10gb"
- Deleted unused indexes to free up resources ES uses to manage their shards
- Increased number of primary shards to 175 with the goal of keeping shard size under 50GB and have approximately a shard per processor
- Set client index batch size to 10MB, which seemed to work very well for us because the size of documents indexed varied drastically (from KBs to MBs)

Hope this helps others

Answer (score 0):

I have run similar workloads and your best bet is to run hourly indices and run optimize on older indices to keep segments in check.